# mongoose update user profile, without user entering password

Tags: mongoose

Using Node Express Mongoose, I want logged in users to able to update their profile WITHOUT having to provide their password again on the update form. They provided it at login and received a JWT.

The issue I am having is that I've set up Mongoose to require the password.
So the API I'm building gives the bad request error when the user update form is submitted and does not contain the password.

The JWT does not contain the password, so I can't get it from there.

```
const config = require("config");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlenghth: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 1024,
    trim: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 30,
    trim: true,
  }
});

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: this._id,
      username: this.username,
      name: this.name,
      isAdmin: this.isAdmin,
    },
    config.get("jwtPrivateKey")
  );
  return token;
};

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

function validateUser(req) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
    password: Joi.string()
      .regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,255}$/)
      .required(),
    name: Joi.string().min(3).max(30).required(),
  });
  return schema.validate(req);
}

exports.User = User;
exports.validateUser = validateUser;
```

the route looks like this:

```
router.post("/", validate(validateUser), async (req, res) => {
  let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

  user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ["username", "password", "name"]));
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

  await user.save();
  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
  res
    .header("x-auth-token", token)
    .send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "username", "name"]));
});

router.put("/:id", [auth, validate(validateUser)], async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password, // This is what I DON'T want
      name: req.body.name,
    }
  );
  if (!user)
    return res.status(404).send("The user with the given ID was not found.");

  res.send(user);
});
```